# Could you estimate the probability of arrivals of a poisson process?

Tags: inference, stochastic-processes, unbiased-estimator, poisson-process

Let $T_i$ ~ $exp(\lambda)$ be i.i.d exponential random variables, with unknown $\lambda$.
These are the time intervals of the poisson process.
And $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^nT_i$, are the arriving time of the poisson process.
Suppose we are given an observation $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_k)$ of arriving times,is it possible to find an estimate of the probability that there are $k$ arrivals in time period of $t$?

E.g Probability that there are $3$ arrivals in $6$ seconds.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Hint: what's the corresponding Poisson distribution for this problem (setup: # of events per unit time)?

Comment: I know the number of arrivals in a time period of $t$,$N(t)$ follows a poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$ . What I am struggling now is to find an estimate of  $\mathbb{P}(N(t)) = k )= \frac{(e^{-t\lambda)}(t\lambda)^k}{k!}$